# parse xlsx file add marker to map

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, google-maps, xlsx

In my code below I am trying to upload a xlsx file, the file contains Latitutde and Longitude data, which I want to display on my googlemap.

In the handleFiles function I am able to upload the xlsx file, then it reads the xlsx file into json array as result. I selected the Lat Long data from the result json array into an other array called "out". I am trying to get the "out" array outside of my handleFile function and add it to the initMap() function, in order to use the lat long values for adding markers on my map. But I am having trouble, cause if I make the out variable global, I get an empty array. Can anyone help me ?

```
 function handleFile(e) {
 //Get the files from Upload control
    var files = e.target.files;
    var i, f;
    var x = [];
    var y = [];
    var out = [];

 //Loop through files
    for (i = 0, f = files[i]; i != files.length; ++i) {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        var name = f.name;
        reader.onload = function (e) {
            var data = e.target.result;

            var result;
            var workbook = XLSX.read(data, { type: 'binary' });

            var sheet_name_list = workbook.SheetNames;
            sheet_name_list.forEach(function (y) { /* iterate through sheets */
                //Convert the cell value to Json
                var roa = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(workbook.Sheets[y]);
                if (roa.length > 0) {
                    result = roa;
                }
            });
           //Get Long, values from results array and save to 

            for (i=0; i<result.length; i++) {
                obj = result[i];
                y.push(obj.Latitude);
                x.push(obj.Longitude);

        }

        for (i=0;i<x.length;i++){
            out.push([x[i],y[i]]);
            };

        };
        reader.readAsArrayBuffer(f);
    }

}
//Change event to dropdownlist
 $(document).ready(function(){
  $('#files').change(handleFile);

 });

  var map;
  function initMap() {
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      center: {lat: 48.7758459, lng: 9.1829321},
      zoom: 8
    });
  }
```

Comment: What does the data currently look like?  How are you trying to create the markers?  What isn't working?